# ¿Cómo se interpreta un "yo creo que tampoco"?

Tags: gramática

Estaba escribiéndome con un amigo cuando él dijo

> Yo creo que Juan no se irá de casa

A lo que yo respondí:

> Yo creo que tampoco

Tras escribir mi frase me quedé pensativo porque no me sonó bien: lo que quise decir es "yo tampoco creo que Juan se vaya de casa", pero me salió decirlo usando [*tampoco*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Z3d5Wg1).

Así que me pregunto: ¿tiene esta frase el mismo significado? ¿tiene sentido en general?

Comment: La única interpretación posible que se me ocurre para ese orden de palabras es: «yo creo que tampoco (iré)». Para lo que tenías en mente, sólo me sale «yo tampoco lo creo».

Comment: Aun cuando estoy de acuerdo con el comentario de @guillem, creo que tu frase se puede entender por el contexto. Lo que no quita para que sea incorrecta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En tu caso, se puede decir que la respuesta más clara y directa sería:

> Yo tampoco lo creo.

El `también/tampoco` en tu caso se aplica al verbo `creer`.

Por otro lado, en la respuesta que tú diste, lo que haces es acortar la frase completa, que sería

> Yo creo que Juan tampoco se irá de casa.

El `también/tampoco` en este caso se aplicaría al verbo `ir`, lo que no es tan correcto. ¿Por qué?:

- Pues eres tú quien quiere indicar que concuerda con tu interlocutor, respecto de si Juan se irá o no.
- No es Juan quien *tampoco* ser irá de casa, lo que hace pensar en otra persona que también se irá. De ahí que no es bueno aplicar el `también/tampoco` al verbo ir (que en este caso está aplicado sobre Juan).

Comment: Me parece más correcto *Yo tampoco lo creo*. Con este significado, el verbo *creer* es transitivo.

Comment: @Gorpik tienes razón, acabo de editar mi respuesta.

Comment: Gran respuesta. Me sonaba mal pero no fue hasta leer tu respuesta que me di cuenta del porqué.

Answer (score 2):

Gramaticalmente no es un error, y de hecho creo que es bastante frecuente. Yo lo consideraría poco recomendable porque implica una lógica enrevesada, pero la verdad funciona como lo haría cualquier otro adverbio oracional:

Oración principal: Yo creo [esto].

Oración subordinada 1: Yo tampoco creo [esto]

Oración subordinada 2: Juan no se irá de casa.

Todo junto:

> Yo creo que tampoco creo que Juan no se irá de casa.

Aquí el *tampoco* es un adverbio oracional y, como es normal, puede usarse solo, elidiendo toda la oración que determina. De hecho nadie repite la información en la oración subordinada, a menos que un profesor te lo exija explícitamente. Es una regla de la pragmática.

Las siguientes oraciones son equivalentes sintácticamente:

> Yo creo que sí. (Yo creo que sí es correcta la afirmación planteada por su padre)
>
> Yo creo que mañana. (Yo creo que mañana voy a pasar por tu casa)
>
> Yo creo que tampoco. (Yo creo que tampoco estoy de acuerdo)

Answer (score 1):

No. Las dos frases no tienen el mismo significado. Yo nunca usaría tu respuesta "`Yo creo que tampoco`" porque me suena incompleta.

La posición de "tampoco" en la oración depende de lo que se quiere decir. Por ejemplo:

**Primer uso:**

> Creo que Juan no se irá de la casa
>
> Yo tampoco creo.

Esto significa que la primera persona piensa que Juan no se irá de la casa y la segunda persona opina lo mismo.

Así lo decimos aquí en Colombia aunque una respuesta que no daría lugar a dudas debería ser "Yo también creo lo mismo".

Cuando la frase se plantea en forma "negativa" siempre usamos "tampoco" pero si se plantea de forma "afirmativa" respondemos "también".

> Yo creo que Juan se va de la casa
>
> Yo también creo.

**Segundo uso**

> Creo que Juan no se ira de la casa (pero no se María).
>
> Yo creo que María tampoco.

En este caso la segunda persona no es que solo opine lo mismo que la primera sino que además opina que Maria va a hacer lo mismo que Juan y no se irá de la casa.  Si la primera frase es afirmativa, la segunda usaría "también"

> Creo que Juan se va de la casa
>
> Yo creo que María también